# asp.net dropdown list issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a dropdown list which contains a number of items. I added a default list item to the dropdown.

For example, I have 4 list items in the dropdown:

1. Apple
2. banana
3. grapes
4. mango

I want to add a default list item of: **please select item**, which is not displayed in all list items in the dropdown.

How is this possible?

Comment: How are you doing this now such that it "displays in all listitems"?  Show the code.

Comment: How do you add the listitem? Pls share you code.

Answer (score 7):

this may help

```
dropdwnlist.Items.Insert(0, "please select item");
```

Comment: It is added in dropdown.I want it is should not added to dropdown

Comment: @SantuSrinu may i know the reason y u dont want to add it to dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding the "Select One" item to the drop down from a reference table in a database (i.e. databinding) make sure to set the

```
AppendDataBoundItems="true" so that  the form will append the new item BEFORE performing a databind.
```

One of my drop downs looks like this. It uses a datasource.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPackageStatus" runat="server" Width="200px"
AppendDataBoundItems="true"  BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px"
DataSourceID="sdsPackageStatus" 
DataTextField="PackageStatus" DataValueField="PackageStatus">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the item you want as the default is in the list. This means you will need to add an item called 'Please select item' to the drop down list.

Comment: k, i dont want add item as default item,is it possible to show--- please select item ---but it is not default item and it is not to display listitem in dropdown.Just like a statement in dropdown.When open dropdown it should display all listitem as usual

Comment: You might be able to come up with something in javascript but that is the only way. I have never done this so i dont know how dificult it is to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, this is too simple thing

```
    private void BindCountryList()
    {
        List<Country> list = GetCountryList();
        list.Insert(0, new Country { CountryName = "Please select" });
        ddCountry.DataSource = list;
        ddCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddCountry.DataValueField = "CountryName";
        ddCountry.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like follows

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            DropDownList1.Text = "Please Select Item";
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

The above code will display the "Please Select Item" only when the index of dd becomes lessthan 0 (i.e., when nothing selected), to test this at page_Load event make the index of dd to -1.

Comment: i dont want add item as default item,is it possible to show--- please select item ---but it is not default item and it is not to display listitem in dropdown.

Comment: Through the above code part I have given the "Please select item" will not be added into the dropdown, but displays when ever the index of the dd will be less than 0(i.e., nothing selected).